# Finding a correct regex for the strings with at least two $0s$

Tags: context-free, regular-expressions

I am learning CFGs and before that I've made a RE (Regular Expression) for the language of "all strings with at least two $0$'s over the alphabet $\Sigma = \{0,1\}$."

I made this: $(0+1)^*0(0+1)^*0(0+1)^*$

I checked the answer and it is: $1^*01^*0(0+1)^*$

Is there any difference between the two?

If mine is also correct, what should be the CFG for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is also correct. Regular languages do not have *unique* regexes. For example, $0^\ast$, $0^\ast 0^\ast$, and $0^\ast 0^\ast 0^\ast$ are different regexes, all representing the language of strings containing only zeroes.

The problem of deciding whether two regexes are *equivalent* (i.e., whether they represent the same language) is actually *very hard*, as mentioned in [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/12278). (Spoiler: it is $\mathbf{PSPACE}$-complete.)

As to your other question (regarding a CFG for the language), here is a hint: *divide and conquer*. Split the regex in multiple "chunks" and try to generate each chunk separately, then pack everything together with the grammar's start symbol.