# Show that the following languages are equal

Tags: formal-languages, automata, finite-automata

I have the following exercise:

Prove that $\{ab,aba\}^*=\{\epsilon\} \cup \{a\}\{ba,baa\}^*\{b,ba\}$.

My idea was to write the words of each of the languages in the following way,for example for the left side:

$(ab)^{n_0}(aba)(ab)^{n_1}(aba)...(aba)(ab)^{n_k}$

And then I try to make assumptions to $n_i$ and $k$. I think this is leading somewhere in the but isn't really satisfying. Can someone give me a hint on how to approach such proofs in a better way?

Comment: Seems to work doesn't it? $(ab)^{n_0}(aba)(ab)^{n_1}(aba)...(aba)(ab)^{n_k}$ is equal to $a(ba)^{n_0}(baa)(ba)^{n_1}(baa)...(baa)(ba)^{n_k-1} b$, assuming $n_k\ge 1$.

Comment: Can you explain why the approach your mentioned "isn't really satisfying"? Are the answers to [_algorithm to determine whether two regexes are equivalent_](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12267) helpful? The equality is $(ab+aba)^*=\epsilon+a(ba+baa)^*(b+ba)$

Comment: @Apass.Jack For me it is not satisfying because I have to study all cases for the $n_i$'s - I just think that this is not clear enough. I thought maybe there is another way to show this.
Regarding the link: Yes I am thinking about converting these expressions to NFAs and compare those.